# Jenkinsfile (scripted) set shell $HOME to ${env.WORKSPACE}

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Docker containers for my builds and the `$HOME` variable of course points to the Jenkins user home (`/home/jenkins`), which can cause problems e.g. if jobs are running in parallel and try to write things to `$HOME` etc.

What is the desired way to set the `$HOME` to the `${env.WORKSPACE}` globally in a scripted Jenkinsfile?

Wrapping all shell steps in `withEnv(["HOME=${WORKSPACE}]){ ... }` seems quite odd.

Here is a minified version of the scripted Pipeline which processes multiple Docker images and wraps the setting of the `$HOME` with `withEnv`:

```
#!groovy
DOCKER_IMAGES = ["python:3.5.0", "python:3.6.5"]

def get_stages(docker_image) {
    stages = {
        docker.image(docker_image).inside {

            // The following line causes a weird issue, where pip tries to 
            // install into /usr/local/... instead of the virtual env.
            // Any help figuring out what's happening is appreciated.
            //
            // def PYTHON_VENV = docker_image.replaceAll('[:.]', '') + 'venv'
            //
            // So we set it to 'venv' for all parallel builds now
            def PYTHON_VENV = 'venv'
            withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]){
                stage("${docker_image}") {
                    echo "Running in ${docker_image}"
                }
                stage("Prepare") {
                    sh "echo 'Home is set to:' $HOME"
                    sh "echo 'Workspace is:' ${env.WORKSPACE}"

                    sh "rm -rf ${PYTHON_VENV}"
                    sh "python -m venv ${PYTHON_VENV}"
                    sh """
                        . ${PYTHON_VENV}/bin/activate
                        pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return stages
}


node('master') {

    cleanWs()

    def stages = [:]
    for (int i = 0; i < DOCKER_IMAGES.size(); i++) {
        def docker_image = DOCKER_IMAGES[i]
        stages[docker_image] = get_stages(docker_image)
    }

    parallel stages
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Wrapping all shell steps in withEnv(["HOME=${WORKSPACE}]){ ... } seems quite odd.

Sure it seems quite odd but it sets the working directory of the container and it makes a volume binding to transfer the necessary files into the container. You can see it in the logs...

`docker run -t -d -u 996:994 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/python-test-pipeline@2 -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/python-test-pipeline@2:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/python-test-pipeline@2:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/python-test-pipeline@2@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/python-test-pipeline@2@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** python:alpine cat`